# JavaScript code for HTML5 webpage audio to read a playlist and populate six arrays

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a working HTML5/JavaScript webpage music (player.html).  Within the JavaScript I use six arrays for the individual track details.

```
tracks = 3;

songs = [
' ',
'./music/mp3/song1.mp3',
'./music/mp3/song1.mp3',
'./music/mp3/song1.mp3',
];

thumbnails = [
' ',
'./music/art/song1.jpg',
'./music/art/song1.jpg',
'./music/art/song1.jpg',
];

songContributors = [
" ",
"contributor1",
"contributor2",
"contributor3",
];

songArtists = [
' ',
'artist1',
'artist2',
'artist3',
];

songTitles = [
" ",
"title1",
"title2",
"title3",
];

songComments = [
" ",
"comment1",
"comment2",
"comment3",
];
```

Now that the number of tracks has increased significantly, my rookie code has become clumsy.  I would like to populate the the track information from a ./playlist.txt file located in the same directory as the player.js file.

playlist.txt looks like:

```
contributor1,artist1,title1,comment1
contributor2,artist2,title2,comment2
contributor3,artist3,title3,comment3
```

I would like for the following outcome:

```
songs[0] is " "
songs[1] is artist1-title1.mp3
songs[2] is artist2-title2.mp3
songs[3] is artist3-title3.mp3
thumbnails[0] is " "
thumbnails[1] is artist1-title1.jpg
thumbnails[2] is artist2-title2.jpg
thumbnails[3] is artist3-title3.jpg
songContributors[0] is " "
songContributors[1] is contributor1
songContributors[2] is contributor2
songContributors[3] is contributor3
songArtists[0] is " "
songArtists[1] is artist1
songArtists[2] is artist2
songArtists[3] is artist3
songTitles[0] is " "
songTitles[1] is title1
songTitles[2] is title2
songTitles[3] is title3
songComments[0] is " "
songComments[1] is comment1
songComments[2] is comment2
songComments[3] is comment3
```

The JavaScript code logic cycles through tracks 1-3
(each array index 0 is a space character).

Comment: Instead of arrays try using objects ! It would be much easier and much simple to extract fields .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to use an object containing all information about one single song and storing each of them in an array. By this you can access the property of each song ( object ) easily and without writing too much of code .

For example :

```
  // Creating an array of song object  and adding some properties 

    let  songs = [{
    title: "song title 1 ",
    musicFile: "./musicFile/mp3/song1.mp3",
    thumbnail: "./musicFile/art/song1.jpg",
    contributors: "contributor1",
    comments: "songComments",  //use arrays or obj if multiple
    artist : "artist 1"
  },
    {
      title: "song title 2 ",
      musicFile: "./musicFile/mp3/song2.mp3",
      thumbnail: "./musicFile/art/song2.jpg",
      contributors: "contributor2",
      comments: "songComments", //use arrays or obj if multiple
      artist : "Artist 2"
    },
    {
      title: "song title 3 ",
      musicFile: "./musicFile/mp3/song3.mp3",
      thumbnail: "./musicFile/art/song3.jpg",
      contributors: "contributor3",
      comments: "songComments", //use arrays or obj if multiple
      artist : "artist 3"
    }]

  songs.forEach(song => {
    console.log("This " + song.title)
  
    /* Access all properties inside each song
    song.title
    song.musicFile
    song.thumbnail
    song.contributors
    song.comments
    song.artist
  */
  
  })
```

Comment: @John Marie To create a playlist just store it like same as songs array ( i.e array of objects ) .... Also always use best practices to prevent these types of issues in future

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I made all the changes and modified the code to used the "songs" array of objects. Everything is working.